# Haskell: confused about uses of Num typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm confused about why this works:

```
f :: Num a => a -> a
f x = x * 42
```

But this doesn't:

```
g :: Num a => a -> a
g x = x * 4.2
```

I had understood that `Num` enclosed all types that implemented operators `(+)`, `(-)`, `(*)`. So, if `42` is an `Int` and `4.2` is a `Fractional`, and both types implement the operator `(*)`, why am I getting this error for `g`?:

```
Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from the literal ‘4.2’ 
from the context (Num a)
bound by the type signature for g :: Num a => a -> a
at file.hs:9:6-20
Possible fix:
add (Fractional a) to the context of
the type signature for g :: Num a => a -> a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `Num a` constraint is too broad. Using the interpreter might help:

```
Prelude> :type 42
42 :: Num t => t
Prelude> :type 4.2
4.2 :: Fractional t => t
```

Numeric literals in Haskell are polymorphic, so as the types are saying, the literals are instantiated as any type as long as the type is a `Num` or, respectively, a `Fractional`.

Now look at the type signature of the `(*)` function from the `Num` class:

```
Prelude> :type (*)
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

The `(*)` operator works on any `Num` value, but the two operands have *the same type*. So if you are multiplying by a value of Fractional type (whatever type the literal `4.2` will be instantiated into), the other operand must be Fractional as well, and the same type in particular. This is why the `Num` constraint on your function is too broad: your function cannot work on any `Num` type, but only on `Fractional`s, hence the compiler is saying that you are missing a `Fractional a =>` constraint in the type signature.

If you let the compiler inference the type of your function, it will agree:

```
Prelude> let g x = x * 4.2
Prelude> :type g
g :: Fractional a => a -> a
```

Comment: So, when you say: "but the two operands have the same type", you mean that applying the function this way should work?: **g 3.14**. I've tried **f 3.14** for example, and it worked, that's why I'm so confused :/

Comment: Yes, `g 3.14` works because `3.14` is a Fractional. Also `f 3.14` works because any fractional is also a Num, so 42 can be instantiated as a Fractional value without any problems. Remember that the literals are not of a specific type, but they are of *any* t type as long as t is a Num (or Fractional). I’ll edit the answer later to better elaborate this point.

Comment: I've just tried `g 3.14` and it didn't work (with `g` defined like I said in my post), same error :(

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the answer, the `Num a` constraint in the type is too broad. Change it to `Fractional a` and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell types work differently than it appears you are expecting.

`Num a => a -> a` does not mean "there is some type `a` that is an instance of `Num` for which this takes a value of type `a` and returns a value of type `a`."

It means "For every single type `a` that is an instance of `Num`, this takes a value of type `a` and returns a value of type `a`."

This means that it has to work for any type the caller chooses.  If the caller chooses `a ~ Int` (`~` is the syntax for type equality, which some optional GHC features enable as a constraint) and then calls `g 1`, what `Int` value should that be?

Well, that doesn't work out very well.  `4.2` isn't a valid `Int`.  So the `*` operator fails to type-check, because it can't make the types of its arguments match.

This is why it has a more restrictive type - the types it accepts must be types that the literal `4.2` is a valid representation of. That ends up requiring a `Fractional` constraint.

Type variables in Haskell are universally quantified. They always make statements about *all* types which satisfy their constraints. If there is ever a counter-example possible, things won't type-check.

Answer (score 2):

The numeric constant `42` is defined to be the same as `fromIntegral (42::Integer)`, and any instance of `Num` has an implementation of `fromIntegral`.  It occurs in the expression `x * 42`, so its inferred type is the same as `x`, which is an `instance` of `Num`.  So the compiler calls the proper version of `fromIntegral` for that `Num` `instance` (or rather, does the calculation at compile time) and everything is hunky-dorey.

But a constant with a decimal point tries to convert from a decimal to the type of `x`.  All we know about that type is that it’s an `instance` of `Num`, so it can’t do the conversion in the general case.  There’s no way to represent `4.2` as, say, an `Integer`.

As the error message says, the compiler can convert a decimal constant to any `Fractional` type.  So change the type constraint from `Num` to `Fractional`, and the decimal will work.