# Haskell type explanation

Tags: haskell, types

I don't understand a simple type error for the following code

```
addCustom :: Num a => a -> a
addCustom a = a + 1.2
```

It throws

> Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from the literal `1.2'

and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: confused about uses of Num typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654955/haskell-confused-about-uses-of-num-typeclass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `Fractional a` to the context of `a`.

```
addCustom :: (Fractional a) => a -> a
addCustom a = a + 1.2
```

should work.

---

If you fire up `ghci` and look at the type of `1.2` you'll see

```
(1.2) :: Fractional p => p
```

while the type of `(+)` is

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Which says that the function can be applied to which belongs to type class `Num`.

So while `a -> a` is the type of your function, it doesn't have the context of `Fractional`. Only of `Num`

That's why adding that context solves it.

Comment: `Fractional` [is a subset](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional) of `Num`, so I think you can omit the constraint on `Num`.

Answer (score 6):

Your type signature

```
addCustom :: Num a => a -> a
```

claims `addCustom` works for all numeric types `a`, including e.g. integers.

But `addCustom (0 :: Integer)` would be an error: `a + 1.2` cannot be done with integer arithmetic because `1.2` is not an integer value (it's a fractional number).

So what you need to do is either change the body of your function:

```
addCustom a = a + 1
```

(which works because `1` exists in all numeric types) or change the type signature:

```
addCustom :: Fractional a => a -> a
```

(which restricts `addCustom` so it can only be used with fractional types, where `1.2` is a valid value).